# import psycopg2 in Anaconda shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python, anaconda, psycopg2

I have already installed psycopg2 in git bash. I am using windows 7, python 3.6 and Anaonda 1.7.0

$ pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.7.4-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (853kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 860kB 937kB/s
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.7.4

$ easy_install psycopg2
Searching for psycopg2
Best match: psycopg2 2.7.4
Adding psycopg2 2.7.4 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\users\shihab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Processing dependencies for psycopg2
Finished processing dependencies for psycopg2

Anybody faced the same problem before ?